# Easy solution to Yamabe problem for surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

The [Yamabe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamabe_problem) asks if, given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g_0)$, it is possible to find a [conformal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_equivalence) metric $g$ on $M$ with constant scalar curvature. I would like to know if there is some "easy" proof that this is true in the case of closed oriented surfaces. (Easy should mean, for example, without assuming [Uniformization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) or using Ricci flow).

Comment: That **is** the uniformization theorem---in the dimension 2 case, constant scalar curvature is the same as constant sectional curvature. So basically what you are asking is if there is an easy proof of the uniformization theorem. There are a lot of proofs, all of them use some serious analysis, and I don't think any of them are regarded as "easy".

Answer (score 0):

For zero and negative Yamabe cases the proof is relatively simple. For the full resolution one needs to use the positive mass theorem.